# glTexSubImage3D vs QOpenGLTexture setData

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qtopengl

To my understanding QOpenGLTexture::setData is equivalent to glTexImage3D in case of texture array or 3D texture. Now if I want to use PBO to update the texture at runtime, I need to use glTexSubImage3D instead of glTexImage3D, what is the equivalent in Qt texture for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [asynchronous uploads](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) in no way require the use of `glTexSubImage3D`; they work for [*any* pixel transfer function.](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_transfer_initiation)

Second, `setData` ***is*** the equivalent of the `SubImage`-class of OpenGL functions. Or at least, [most overloads](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopengltexture.html#setData) of `setData` are; the [one that takes a `MipMapGeneration` flag](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopengltexture.html#setData-9) will allocate storage for you (because Qt's OpenGL abstraction is the place where consistency goes to die). So you can use PBOs just fine with `setData`.

Textures in OpenGL are rather like pointers. `allocateStorage` is like allocating memory and storing the allocated memory in a pointer (`int *p = new int[20];`). `setData` is like accessing the allocated object and copying data into it (`p[0] = 5;`). You have to have allocated memory before you can store stuff into it, but you don't need to allocate memory *again* after you've done so before.

Comment: Since I have an array texture, I'm using this one: 

void QOpenGLTexture::setData(int mipLevel, int layer, PixelFormat sourceFormat, PixelType sourceType, const void *data, const QOpenGLPixelTransferOptions * const options = Q_NULLPTR), so from what you say I need to call allocateStorage everytime that I want to transfer the pixels to the texture from PBO right?

Comment: @user3178756: No. Indeed, [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopengltexture.html#allocateStorage-1) makes it clear that you cannot call `allocateStorage` *twice* on the same texture. I was trying to say that it needed to have been called before `setData`, not that there should be a 1:1 mapping between `setData` and `allocateStorage`.

Comment: Thanks! I have another related question: 

GLubyte* ptr = (GLubyte*)m_vPUBONNZ[m_iPBONextIndx]->map(QOpenGLBuffer::WriteOnly);
My texture is QOpenGLTexture::UInt16 and if I use anything other than GLubyte I will get a segmentation fault during rendering, why I can't cast to anything else (like GLushort)  during PBO mapping? How one specifies the type of data for PBO?

Comment: @user3178756: I can't tell; you didn't post all of your relevant code. But I've answered your current question; if you have another, you should ask that.